# Cordova geofence plugin is not working with Ionic 4

Tags: cordova-plugins, ionic4

While adding cordova-plugin-geofence I am getting the following error

> Cannot find module '../../src/cordova/platform_metadata' Require stack:
>
> ```
> - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/Context.js
> - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js
> - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js
> - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/plugman.js
> - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/cordova-lib.js
> - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/help.js
> - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/cli.js
> - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
> ```

And also the following error

> Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-geofence': CordovaError: Version of installed plugin: "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support@2.0.2" does not
> satisfy dependency plugin requirement
> "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support@^1.6.0". Try --force to use
> installed plugin as dependency. at
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:544:43

Comment: When i install latest version of cordova-plugin-add-swift support and add platform ios again it throws another error: 

Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-geofence': CordovaError: Version of installed plugin: "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support@2.0.2" does not satisfy dependency plugin requirement "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support@^1.6.0". Try --force to use installed plugin as dependency.
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:544:43

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following steps

```
cordova platform remove ios
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-add-swift-support
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-add-swift-support@1.6.0
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-geofence
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geofence
cordova platform add ios
cordova clean
```

Let me know if its working or not.